# Git rebase fails with "error: Your local changes to the following files may be overwritten by merge"

Tags: git, git-rebase

Commands I used:

```
git pull origin master
git checkout ratiosheet
git rebase dev16
```

This is my issue, it's asking me to edit todo ?

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: It looks like you haven't committed some files before pulling/rebasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that your local git repository is clean before attempting a merge or rebase.

E.g. by stashing all local changes with `git stash push -u` (or `git stash save -u` on older versions of git).

If you want to restore your most recently stashed changes again, e.g. after finishing the merge, you can use `git stash apply`.

You probably want to perform a `git rebase --abort` first, as you have already started a rebase session.

Comment: My repo is clean. No uncommitted/unstaged/untracked changes

Comment: @cSekhar3126 That's not what the error says? `common/cfc/fa_data.cfc` has changed and would be overwritten